# How to check if an object in a list has a certain property

Tags: python, list

We have some objects with properties

```
class my_object:
    def __init__(self, type, name):
        self.type = type
        self.name = name
```

And a list which contains many object with different `type` and `name` values.

What I need is a comprehension which does something like:

```
if my_object.type == 'type 1' in object_list:
    object_list.remove(all objects with name == 'some_name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is :

```
if any(obj.type == 'type 1' for obj in object_list):
    object_list = [obj for obj in object_list if obj.name != 'some_name']
```

Comment: not efficient ... get rid of the if ... you are looping through twice for no reason

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- What do you mean?  The looping really isn't all that costly and to factor the other test into the list-comp would change the logic (although maybe only slightly).

Comment: ahh yeah your right .. i guess it does ... I just read the problem statement wrong

Comment: @Mike Graham: But the OP said that it does. Why are you not clear?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are  looking for:

```
object_list = filter(lambda x: x.name != 'some_name', object_list)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think so too... Although, I'd advise the list-comp here.

Comment: meh ... why? I know filter isnt more efficient with lambdas ... but to me what you are doing is "filtering" the list, and so using filter is more natural to me ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- I suppose it's because every time you see a `lambda`, you have to figure out what it's doing.  I think most people prefer not to look at them if possible arguing that the syntax for the list-comprehension is more elegant and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
if hasattr(my_object,"some_attribute") : doSomething()
```

although in your case I think you want

```
filter(lambda x:not hasattr(x,"name") or x.name != "some_name",my_list_of_objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
def remove_objects(obj_list,*args,**kwargs):
    for n_count,node in enumerate(obj_list[::]):
        del_node=False
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            if hasattr(node,str(k)):
                if getattr(node,str(k))==v:
                    del_node=True
                    break
        if del_node:
            del obj_list[n_count]
```

And use it like:

```
class HelloWorld(object):
    lol="haha"
my_list_of_objects=[HelloWorld for x in range(10)]
remove_objects(my_list_of_objects,lol="haha")
```

Comment: dont modify a list as you are iterating over it! especially when going from low to high, but really even when going high to low.

Comment: Wow... That looks ... Complicated.  Also, I'm hesitant to say that I believe this works because you're deleting objects from the list as you iterate over it.  Finally, rather than keeping a counter yourself, you could use the builtin `enumerate`.